# Prefix.pch error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I get the following error in Xcode, when building project. Can someone help me fix it?

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

with this error:

```
Prefix.pch:6:38: error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
Prefix.pch:7:28: error: UIKit/UIKit.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What did you do to the standard template Xcode gives you? You don't usually get an error in `pch`. Did you edit `pch`? Try creating a new project. Does it gives you an error? Then your installation is quite heavily broken.

Comment: I am reinstalling the SDK now.

Comment: After reinstalling, it still gives me the error

Comment: How are you building the project? Are you clicking the build button? Which template did you choose? If you create a project from a template, and just click the build button, it shouldn't give any error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're not linking against the frameworks correctly, or more likely aren't copying the headers somehow.  Likely you accidentally changed the include path of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the Frameworks:

UIKit.framework
Foundation.framework